# how to implement a user authentication system and create accounts for social network login?

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am a newbie of user authentication, currently I am playing around with Azure AD B2C, it seems good but I want to create native pages in my app for user sign up and login instead of using the azure policy, so I want to implement this function in my app:

A user can sign up in to my app by filling his email and password, and then, a set of optional profile attributes. He also can login in to my app by using Facebook or Google, etc; and in the first time login, my app will ask the user to fill in the user profile and create an account for him in my app. So the user will eventually have an account for my app. I think this is very common in mobile apps, but I just don't know what is its structure and how it works, here is an example:

[Adobe XD sign up or login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYGCp.jpg)

The other question is how the server should verify a request sent by a user? Does it need to verify the Facebook access token, Google access token or my app access token embedded in the request separately? Or is there a way to safely verify the user identity in the same way?

I don't know how to put all the things together to make an app, please tell me how to implement it, or which services (like azure ad b2c) can satisfy my need, or please recommend some open source ios app projects which implement this function.

Thanks a lot, I've been thinking this problem for a couple of days :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide what solution would you like to use: your own solution or external, free or commercial. I can suggest you to take a look to https://auth0.com. They have manual for iOS: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ios-swift/getting-started. Also you can find a lot of examples how to use auth0 in Internet.

Please be careful if you will use Facebook and Google APIs. Someday we had an error in our application because of gender field. Facebook API return MALE/FEMALE, but Google also have OTHER and this caused an error - on our side we had only MALE/FEMALE gender in our Enumeration and no OTHER type (gender validation failed because of this).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I still don't know how to validate an access token in a request, do I need to compare it with something, or use different endpoints provided by different identity providers to get the validation result?

Comment: Any solution have 2 services to retrieve token and to validate it, otherwise you are not able to be sure that token valid or invalid (incl. expired). Please take a look to this article https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/. There is diagram to show flow, this one also good https://docs.sitefinity.com/sf-images/default-source/installation-and-administration-guide/sso.png?sfvrsn=0. I suggest you to find real authentication example for iOS to deep into details how you might implement it. For example: https://www.raywenderlich.com/99431/oauth-2-with-swift-tutorial.

Comment: From example which I sent you in previous comment: "OAuth2 works with the following four actors:
*authorization server*: responsible for authentication and authorization; provides the access token. *resource server*: in charge of serving up resources if a valid token is provided."

Comment: Thank you very much, that's helpful, I start understanding what I should do and how to do now, thanks for your help again: )